# Writing a script to select one side of each rectangle for a large set of rectangles

Tags: python, scripting, hair

In order to use the surface deform modifier with the hair I made (nothing special about it), I converted that hair to a mesh. When I converted that hair to a mesh, each hair had no thickness and was just a series of vertices, so I thickened each hair with the extrusion operation. The issue now is that all of the hairs face the same way. Basically its just a bunch of separate lines made of faces. It'd be perfect if I had a script that could select one side of each of the lines of faces. That way, I could save that as a vertex group, and use small chunks of each to mix up the directions the hair faces. That said, I have no idea how to accomplish that in blender. Can someone help me out here?

I know there are other ways to go about solving my initial issue other than using mesh hair, but I've been wrestling with this on and off for weeks, and this is the only solution I've found that really works for my application.